# NSURLSession multiple concurrent requests refused by Exchange server

Tags: ios, concurrency, exchangewebservices, nsurlsession

I have replaced my `NSURLConnection` code with `NSURLSession` to fetch data with EWS Exchange server. My app makes multiple concurrent API calls.  It was working fine but now, when I am using `NSURLSession` some of my API calls get correct response and some gets the error from exchange server as follows:

```
{
"s:Envelope" =     {
    "s:Body" =         {
        "m:GetItemResponse" =             {
            "m:ResponseMessages" =                 {
                "m:GetItemResponseMessage" =                     {
                    ResponseClass = Error;
                    "m:DescriptiveLinkKey" =                         {
                        text = 0;
                    };
                    "m:Items" =                         {
                    };
                    "m:MessageText" =                         {
                        text = "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., Cannot open mailbox /o=First Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group(FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=00037FFEE6F0D3D2.";
                    };
                    "m:MessageXml" =                         {
                        "t:Value" =                             (
                                                            {
                                Name = InnerErrorMessageText;
                                text = "Too many concurrent connections opened.";
                            },
                                                            {
                                Name = InnerErrorResponseCode;
                                text = ErrorTooManyObjectsOpened;
                            },
                                                            {
                                Name = InnerErrorDescriptiveLinkKey;
                                text = 0;
                            }
                        );
                    };
                    "m:ResponseCode" =                         {
                        text = ErrorInternalServerError;
                    };
                };
            };
            "xmlns:m" = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages";
            "xmlns:t" = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types";
        };
        "xmlns:xsd" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
        "xmlns:xsi" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    };
    "s:Header" =         {
        "h:ServerVersionInfo" =             {
            MajorBuildNumber = 1034;
            MajorVersion = 15;
            MinorBuildNumber = 11;
            MinorVersion = 1;
            xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types";
            "xmlns:h" = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types";
            "xmlns:xsd" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
            "xmlns:xsi" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        };
    };
    "xmlns:s" = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
};
```

Apparently the problem is too many connections at same time.

My code flow is:

My `HTTPRequest.m` has a method

```
- (void)fetchData
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        sessionAlive = sessionAlive + 1;

        NSLog(@"sessionCount: %ld", (long)sessionAlive);

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];

        NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfiguration
                                                                     delegate:self
                                                               delegateQueue:nil];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request];

        [dataTask resume];
    });
}

// Some NSURLSession delegates methods here

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
     dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
   didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.data appendData:data];
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
             task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error)
    {
        self.failureBlock ? self.failureBlock(error) : nil;
    }
    else
    {
        NSData *data;

        if (self.data)
        {
            data = [NSData dataWithData:self.data];
        }

        self.successBlock ? self.successBlock(self.redirectLocation, data) : nil;
    }

    [session finishTasksAndInvalidate]; // We must release the session, else it holds strong referance for it's delegate (in our case EWSHTTPRequest).
                                        // And it wont allow the delegate object to free -> cause memory leak
}
```

And I am downloading emails concurrently something like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

foreach (NSString *emailId in emalilIDArray)
    {
     HTTPRequest *request = [HTTPRequest alloc] init];
      [request fetchData];
    }
});
```

I think my problem is that I am making session on each call and but I don't know see other way.

If I cant use a shared-instance session, as I need to associate session's delegate with each HTTPRequest object to handle the response.

Any suggestion or better approach ?

Answer (score 2):

To minimize the architectural changes, I'd probably suggest a singleton that manages the session, but proxies the delegate calls to the relevant object.  In other words:

1. Call a method on that singleton class with the `NSURLRequest` and let it create the task; pass your `HTTPRequest` object to that method, too, so that it knows who to call with the results.
2. In the singleton class, store the newly created `NSURLSession[Data|Download|Upload]Task` object as the key in a dictionary.
3. Store your `HTTPRequest` object as the corresponding value.
4. Write a giant pile of per-task delegate methods that each look up the task in the dictionary and call the same delegate method on the correct `HTTPRequest` object.
5. When the task finishes, remove it from the dictionary to release the `HTTPRequest` object.

Alternatively, if all the `HTTPRequest` object is really doing is providing a bunch of authentication handling methods and accumulating the data, you might consider creating a singleton class that takes an `NSURLRequest` object and a block instead, and runs that block when you've gotten the data.

For that matter, if you aren't processing the data incrementally, you might also consider passing that block directly as the `completionHandler` block for the task and let the session itself handle the data accumulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as many sessions as you want but in case you create too many connections to the server I would offer:

It needs to have shared operation queue for your requests inside some singleton but
instead of usage main or global operation queue from GCD consider usage of NSOperationQueue and NSOperations. NSOperationQueue can have the limit for number of tasks which can be executed in the same time.

var operationCount: Int The number of operations currently in the queue.

You can limit the number of simultaneous connections as result.
as far as I remember dispatch_get_global_queue does not have such possibility because you just use external existing queue and cannot assign limitation to it.

So instead of

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{...
```

you can create NSBlockOperation with the same block and add this operation to NSOperationQueue. In case your add more tasks than 'operationCount' only 'operationCount' of requests will be issued. all others will wait while one of executed task is finished.

This is not full code but idea of what you can try

```
 NSOperationQueue *backgroundOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
 backgroundOperationQueue.operationCount = 5;
 NSOperation *blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:yourblock];
[backgroundOperationQueue addOperation:blockOperation];
```

In case you prefer GCD consider usage of Serial queue it allows only one task in the time.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);
```